# many to many database phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, relationship

there is a parent table, he can add more than one children email ids(no. unknown)(primary key).
And a child can have one or 2 parent email ids(mother/father)

This will be a many to many relationship?

could you guide me on constructing this relationship in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You might want to use some sort of model system like NHibernate for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many to many relationship in a normal relational database, like MySQL, is normally constructed using a cross link table. That is a table that links to records in the other tables together.

For instance, when you've got tables A and B, you create a third table, C, which can look (very simplified) like this:

```
A      B         C
==     ==        ====
A1     B1        A1B3
A2     B2        A2B1
A3     B3        A2B2
                 A3B2
```

So in this cross link table, you can see that record A2 is linked to two records in B, just as B2 is linked to two records in A. Of course, this schema is simplified. A1 is actually the keyfield of table A and A1B1 is a primary key that consists of two fields, one having a foreign key constraint to the key of table A and one having an FK to table B.

It doesn't always have to be a many to many relationship. For instance, you can say that a person has to parents, which also are persons. Since it's not very likely for people to have more that two biological parents, you can safely give a row in `person` a `fatherid` and a `motherid`, both of which refer to the same `person` table. So, like always, it depends on your exact needs.

Comment: Oh. Apparently, these kinds of tables are known by [many names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).